# Enabled/Disabled Button based on User Permission [C# MySQL]

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying with some code to disable/enable button based on user permission.
However, the code seem like nothing change to the system.
Anyone can advice/guide me on these? Thanks in advance.

```
  public partial class frmTest : Form
{

    public string UserID;}


 private void frmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshActivate();

 private void RefreshActivate()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        MySQLClass.query(ds, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + UserID + "'");

        string strPermission = ds.Tables[0].Columns["permission"].ToString();

            if (strPermission == "Admin")
            {
                btnActivate.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (strPermission == "ReadOnly")
            {
                btnActivate.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnActivate.Enabled = false;
            }

        }}
```

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BevH8.png

Comment: Have you checked the content of the ```ds``` dataset after executing the query ?

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Hi, yea... I've tried to figure out the problem but no idea yet.

Comment: How many rows are there in the ```users``` table ? Because you select all the rows (without sorting) and then read the 1st one. You would be lucky if you retrieved the row you expected as the 1st one.

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Is it possible to select all rows and read all rows? Can you guide me? Thanks.

Comment: you can iterate on ```ds.Tables[0].Rows``` with a ```foreach``` loop but I think a ```WHERE``` clause is missing in your query to select the rows related to your current user. Example : ```... FROM users u WHERE u.login = 'loginOfMyCurrentUser' ```

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Yes, there is a WHERE clause, I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first the permission if not null

```
if(!strPermission.Equals(null)//or ""
 {
    if (strPermission == "Admin")
    {
        btnActivate.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (strPermission == "ReadOnly")
    {
        btnActivate.Enabled = false;
    }
 }else{ 
    //value of permision is empty
    MessageBox.Show("Permission is empty");
 }
```

Now if the permission is empty it is something to do or fix when retrieving the data